# Why Scapy added 'c2' byte in Dot11 element infomation?

Tags: wifi, scapy

I just followed the steps from [Forging WiFi Beacon](https://www.4armed.com/blog/forging-wifi-beacon-frames-using-scapy/), but my output is strange, it added 'c2' byte between '0f' and 'ac' byte, Why this happened? How do I solve this problem?

Please look at the image [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're on Python 3 (as IPython > 5 requires Python > 3)

In that case, you should remember to append a `b` in front of bytes strings: `b"\x01\x02..."` as it is required on Python 3+